# Sort TreeView by Key

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

How can I sort a WinForms TreeView by using the nodes' keys, rather than by their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it any way you like with the TreeView.TreeViewNodeSorter property.  There's a good example in the [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter.aspx) for it.